# Atom [Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: spawn EACCES

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

The package linter-flake8 popped up an error message

> [Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: spawn
> /Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/bin EACCES.

The detailed info Atom gave me is:

> /Users/apple/.atom/packages/linter/lib/linter-registry.js:154 [Linter]
> Error running Flake8 Error: spawn /Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/bin
> EACCES at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:246) at onErrorNT
> (internal/child_process.js:429) at processTicksAndRejections
> (internal/process/task_queues.js:81) (anonymous) @
> /Users/apple/.atom/packages/linter/lib/linter-registry.js:154

I use the Mac OS system now, and I double-checked that both flake8 and linter-flake8 are installed through the terminal (the path that the terminal showed for flake8 is `/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/bin`, and I used this address for the executable path in the linter-flake8 settings). I've been dealing with this error for two days but nothing has been solved yet. I really appreciate it if someone can help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it looks like you've set your setting to `/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/bin` but it should be `/Users/apple/Library/Python/2.7/bin/flake8`

Comment: Thanks, Anthony! Bue that's not the major problem. I figured out that there's something wrong with my path and my python version, after I changed it the problem is gone. Thanks anyway!